# Set user agent in PhantomJS and Protractor

Tags: phantomjs, protractor

I am using Protractor with PhantomJS. How can I set the user agent that PhantomJS sends? Can it be different for different tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent` under `capabilities`:

```
capabilities: {
    "browserName": "phantomjs",
    "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
}
```